# Animation of a train departing a station with a varying number of carriages using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a new content creator streaming on Twitch, and want to make a few scenes set at a train station for when I get raids or Hype Trains. All scenes and assets are complete.

I need animations for the train departing the station and passengers alighting from the train.

For the train departing, the train would have a different amount of carriages:
<> Raid: 1 carriage per 68 people in the raid (e.g. 12 carriages for a raid of 750)
<> Hype Train: 1 carriage per level reached (e.g. 5 carriages if Hype Train reaches level 5)

The goal is to set the length of the train to a certain amount of carriages, and then run in a slide show the full train departing as a single group using the Fly Out (to right) animation.

Pseudocode for the raid train:

```
Set raid = number of people in raid
Copy carriage from carriage slide
If raid > 0
(
    Move back loco and carriages left 1 carriage length
    Paste carriage from carriage slide
    Group new carriage with rest of train
    Modify duration of exit animation (5 seconds per carriage)
    Set raid = raid-68
)
else
(
    Run exit animation
)
```

By "back loco", this particular train will have a locomotive on both ends, similar to the InterCity 125 trains in the UK. This will be moved along with the carriages when a new carriage is added to the front.

My (incomplete and untested) code:

```vb
''Declare all variables used in script
Dim raid As Integer
Dim raidfile As String
Dim carriage As Object
Dim backloco As Object
Dim train As Object
''Call the number of people in the raid. Type this into raid.txt first.
raidfile = ActivePresentation.Path & "\raid.txt"
raid = 0
Open raidfile For Input As #1
Input #1, raidfile
raid = raidfile
Close #1
''Place 1 carriage for every 68 passengers, moving the existing train (including back loco but not front loco) to the left to make space
With ActivePresentation
    .Slides(27).Shapes.Copy
End With

Function getTrain() As Shape
Set getTrain = ActivePresentation.Slides(23).Shapes("Group 1")
End Function

Do While raid > 0
With ActivePresentation
    Set train = getTrain
    train.Left = train - train.Width
    .Slides(23).Shapes.Paste
End With
```

At this point the first carriage is pasted from another slide, but I don't know how to select the newly-pasted item and group it with the loco.

The idea is to repeat the code of "move train left 1 carriage length--paste new carriage--group new carriage with rest of train--drop "raid" integer by 68" until the "raid" variable hits 0, and then run the animation.

Comment: When you do the `.Slides(23).Shapes.Paste` your shape would be the one on top (being the last one being added to the slide) , so you could just `Dim pastedShape As Shape: Set pastedShape  = .Slides(23).Shapes(Slides(23).Shapes.Count)`  to get it and "select" it (however, avoid at any cost using select, also useless since once you `Set` a shape you can do things with it already when you need).

Comment: Also, now that I am having a better look, I see the function `getTrain` is right in the middle of the code, but I guess this is just because this is a preparatory sketch. However, it is saying that the shape is called "Group 1", this could be used to find it as per above, or should it actually be an effect of what happens after being found?